# ajax data doesnt work in click event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I want an alert to show up, after the second click. first in the `li` then in the `div.button`.

**HTML**

```
<li onclick="$(document).ShowPosts(4)"></li>
<div class="button">[show posts]</div>
```

this function has an inner ajax call to retrieve the number of posts.
Once I successfully has returned the data with ajax, and click the button, the alert doesnt show up.

**JQUERY**

```
jQuery.fn.ShowPosts = function(id_user) {
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "posts.php",
     data: {
       'id_user': id_user
     },
     success: function(data) {
       var total_posts = data;
     });

   $(".button").on('click', function(e) {
       alert(total_posts);
     }
   });
}
```

It looks like the click event from buttom doesn't recognize the varia ble retrieved by ajax...what am doing wrong?

Comment: declare `total_posts` outside the ajax. until the ajax will not succeed, the `total_post` will be `undefined`.

Comment: if I define `total_posts` before the ajax call, for example `var total_post=2000` when clicking the  `div.button` it shows up an alert saying `2000` not the number retrieved by the ajax call.

Comment: Remove the `var` before `total_posts` in the `success` callback.

Comment: @MoshFeu I removed it.  It work well now, thank you.

Comment: feel free to publish a short answer to mark it!

Comment: Answered, thanks :) and good luck!

Comment: `$(".button")....` should not be in the function ShowPosts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a variable using `var` insides a function, its scope is only the function so it's not accessible outside of it.

So, you need to declare it outside the `success` function and set it in this function. Only then you will get the right value.

For example, this is not working becuase `a`'s declaring is inside `b` function:

```js
function b() {
  var a = 8;
}

b();
console.log(a);
```

This is also, will not work (the value of `a` will not change outside the `b` function scope)

```js
var a = 8;
function b() {
  var a = 9;
  console.log('a inside b()', a);
}

b();
console.log('a outside b()', a);
```

So, you need to declare it at start and **override** it in the `success` callback.

```js
var a = 8;
function b() {
  a = 9;
  console.log('a inside b()', a);
}

b();
console.log('a outside b()', a);
```